# auto_test_package throws error even though test_package passes

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I'm trying to write tests for an R package using `testthat`. Both `testthat` and `devtools` are installed using `install_github`, test code is in `tests/testthat` and `test-all.R` is in `tests`. using R CMD check I get

> - checking tests ...
>     Running ‘test-all.R’ OK

and

> >test()
>   Testing FASTIN
>   Loading FASTIN
>   IO test : ......

similarly

> > test_package('FASTIN')
>   IO test : ......

Very pleased with my first testthat experience, I now wanted to auto-monitor further development with `auto_test_package', but calling 9it from the package root dir gives:

> >auto_test_package('./')
>   IO test : ......
>   Error in digest(path, file = TRUE) : 
>     The specified pathname is not a file: /Users/phil/Work/FASTIN-R/FASTIN-R/tests/testthat

I guess this means that the tests run but something goes wrong once they're done? Trying to set this up manually with `auto_test` gives the same error:

> >auto_test('./R/', './tests/')
>   IO test : ......
>   Error in digest(path, file = TRUE) : 
>     The specified pathname is not a file: /Users/phil/Work/FASTIN-R/FASTIN-R/tests/testthat

I tried setting `auto_test` up to use `test/testthat` instead, but this time the tests are run but throws errors as well...

> auto_test('./R/','./tests/testthat/')
>   IO test : 12
>   1. Error: SI import works correctly ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   nchar(SI.predators) > 0 & nchar(SI.preys) > 0 is not TRUE
>   1: addSI(SI.predators = SI.predators, SI.preys = SI.preys, Frac.Coeffs.mean = Frac.Coeffs.mean, Frac.Coeffs.var = Frac.Coeffs.var) at test_io.R:10
>   2: stopifnot(nchar(SI.predators) > 0 & nchar(SI.preys) > 0) at /Users/phil/Work/FASTIN-R/FASTIN-R/R/DataIO.R:56
>   3: stop(sprintf(ngettext(length(r), "%s is not TRUE", "%s are not all TRUE"), ch), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)

What am I doing wrong here? I'm a bit puzzled and haven't found an immediate answer in the `testthat` code on github...

any help would be much appreciated!
cheers

Comment: maybe a path problem?  have you tried opening the file as an .Rproj?  when I work on my package via the .Rproj I can run `auto_test_package()` with no filepath and it knows to load the package etc.